# Undefined method `new' for "ExceptionNotification::Rack":String error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My project comes with a readme file that has a step of commands to execute in order to run locally.

1. `gem install bundler`
2. `bundle install`
3. `bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate`
4. `ADMIN_PASSWORD=localpassword bundle exec rails server`

I got errors:

```
constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
constant ::Bignum is deprecated
```

while executing step 3. It turned out I had to upgrade my project to the recent version of Rails. While executing step number 3, I get the following error,

```
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:35:in 'build': undefined method 'new' for "ExceptionNotification::Rack":String (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  next
```

and a solution I found was to update line in a `exception_notification` gem but this project does not seem to be using that gem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would like you to confirm a couple of things first. Is your gemset is properly set? Did you searched `exception_notification` in Gemfile.lock? I guess it is some sort of dependent gem.

Comment: Can you share the link which you follow?